# Putting just a list gives an error message

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am very new to Python just to make that clear. I made a list just to try out different things you can do with IDLE:

```
list_of_letters=[a,b,c]
```

That was all I wrote and got an error message

```
NameError: name 'a' is not defined
```

However, when I made the same list with numbers everything worked. What is the issue here? How can I - for example - make a list of strings?

Comment: Here `list_of_letters=[a,b,c]` not list of letters, it is actually a list of variables.

Comment: you have to define what is a,b ,c , i.e, if they are string or integer or float.

Comment: @earthquake Strings in python are represented with either a single quote or double quote.

Answer (score 1):

About `python` [list](https://docs.python.org/3.7/tutorial/datastructures.html). I suppose you wanted to create a list with strings as single characters. But in this case you made a list with three variables, which doesn't assigned yet to the name a,b,c you passed to the list. That is why the error message occurred. You have to first define them some way first. If you want to pass them as [strings](https://docs.python.org/3/library/stdtypes.html) you have to use quotes (double or single)  "", or '' surround them:

```
list_of_letters = ["a", "b", "c"]
```

Comment: Thank you! I didn't know about the "/' rule, everything works perfectly now.

Answer (score 0):

`list_of_letters=[a,b,c]` implies there exist **variables**, **classes**, etc with names a, b and c, which you have not defined.
To do what you're trying to do you should define them as "a", "b" and "c" (**Strings**).

[Here](https://www.w3schools.com/python/python_lists.asp) is a guide on Python lists

Answer (score 0):

list can contains strings
you need to know strings should come with an quotes

```
list=["a",'b',"'c'"]
print(list)
```

Output:

['a', 'b', "'c'"]

string can comes with single,double and triple qoutes

Comment: It's generally better to avoid naming variables things like `list` that overwrite python builtins.